# Regex PatternRepository pattern on BlackBerry 5 - how to ignore case

Tags: regex, blackberry, pattern-matching

I hope this title makes sense - I need case-insensitive regex matching on BlackBerry 5.

I have a regular expression defined as:

```
    public static final String SMS_REG_EXP = "(?i)[(htp:/w\\.)]*cobiinteractive\\.com/[\\w|\\%]+";
```

It is intended to match "*cobiinteractive.com/*" followed by some text. The preceding (htp:w.) is just there because on my device I needed to override the internal link-recognition that the phone applies (shameless hack).

The app loads at start-up. The idea is that I want to pick up links to my site from sms & email, and process them with my app.

I add it to the PatternRepository using:

```
    PatternRepository.addPattern(
        ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor(),
        GlobalConstants.SMS_REG_EXP,
        PatternRepository.PATTERN_TYPE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION,
        applicationMenu);
```

- On the os 4.5 / 4.7 simulators and on
  a Curve 8900 device (running 4.5),
  this works.
- On the os 5 simulators and the Bold
  9700 I tested, app fails to compile
  the pattern with an
  *IllegalArgumentException("unrecognized
  character after (?")*.

I have also tried (naively) to set the pattern to "/rockstar/i" but that only matches the exact string - this is possibly the correct direction to take, but if so, I don't know how to implement it on the BB.

---

How would I modify my regex in order to pick up case insensitive patterns using the PatternRepository as above?

PS: would the "correct" way be to use the [Cc][Oo][Bb][Ii]2... etc pattern? This is ok for a short string, but I am hoping for a more general solution if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody else has answered this question relating to the `PatternRepository` class, I will self-answer so I can close it.

One way to do this would be to use a pattern like:  [Cc][Oo][Bb][Ii]2[Nn][Tt][Ee][Rr][Aa][Cc][Tt][Ii][Vv][Ee]... etc where for each letter in the string, you put 2 options. Fortunately my string is short.

This is not an elegant solution, but it works. Unfortunately I don't know of a way to modify the string passed to `PatternRepository` and I think the crash when using the `(?i)` modifier is a bug in BB.

Comment: Downvoter for interest is there anything you would like to add?

Answer (score 0):

Well not a real solution for the general problem but this workaround is easy, safe and performant:

As your dealing here with URLs and they are not case-sensitive...
 
(it doesn't matter if we write google.com or GooGLE.COm or whatever)

The most simple solution (we all love [KISS_principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) is to do first a lowercase (or uppercase if you like) on the input and than do a regex match where it doesn't matter whether it's case-sensitive or not because we know for sure what we are dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, however, in this case it is not possible. I am referring to a specific case of adding to the PatternRepository, which is handled by the BlackBerry OS in order to identify strings in the built-in messaging application. As such, I don't know of any way of manipulating the string before the PatternRepository identifies it - hence my problem. Richard

Answer (score 0):

Use the port of the jakarta regex library:
https://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/

If you use unicode support, it's going to eat memory,
but if you just want case insensitive matching,
you simply need to pass the RE.MATCH_CASEINDEPENDENT flag when you compile your regex.

`new RE("yourCaseInsensitivePattern", RE.MATCH_CASEINDEPENDENT | OTHER_FLAGS)`